# modify complex unique constraint based on condition in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to modify an existing complex unique constraint.

table name = A

**AS IS:**
columns = c1 (not null), c2 (not null), c3 (primarykey)

current complex unique constraint is on = (c1, c2)

**TO BE:**
columns = c1 **nullable**, c2 (not null), c3 (primarykey), c4 **nullable**

***In my case either c1 or c4 will be available with values for sure.***

my problem
if c4 is not null, then unique constraint is on (c2, c4)
else unique constraint is on (c1, c2)

could someone help me please?

Comment: The question doesn't quite make sense - you will need to clarify it. "Unique" is determined by looking at pairs of rows, not at individual rows. There must not be two different rows that are duplicates according to your uniqueness definition. So, what if you have two rows, one has `null` c4 and the other non-`null` c4? What must be "unique" between the two rows in that case? They **may** have the same c1 and c2; are they duplicates, or not?

Comment: @mathguy - in my case either c1 or c4 will be available with values for sure.

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with what I asked. Did you take a look at the concrete example I gave in a comment to MT0's answer? If not, why not? If yes - did you understand it? What is the desired handling in that case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `UNIQUE` index:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table_name__c1_c2_c4__u
  ON table_name (c2, c4, NVL2(c4, NULL, c1));
```

Then you can insert the rows:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (c1, c2, c3, c4)
SELECT 1, 1, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 2, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, NULL, 3, 2 FROM DUAL;
```

But, if you try to insert duplicates:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (c1, c2, c3, c4) VALUES (1, 1, 4, 1);
INSERT INTO table_name (c1, c2, c3, c4) VALUES (2, 2, 5, NULL);
INSERT INTO table_name (c1, c2, c3, c4) VALUES (2, NULL, 6, 2);
```

Then they each give the error:

> ```
> ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME__C1_C2_C4__U) violated
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=30484f880e9c9eb63862676d4c67aa03)*

Comment: I asked the OP a question - I see two answers now, before the OP responded, and neither specifies what assumption they make. Here's an example: rows with values (1,2,3,4) and (1,2,3,null). Do they violate uniqueness? Which rule should apply, and **why**? "Duplicates" involve two rows; we have one rule when c4 is `null`, another when it is not - but in my example, c4 is `null` in one row but not `null` in the other, so which rule should apply, and why?